# Can't connect to SQL Server from other computers

Tags: sql-server

I want to ask you about a problem.

I have developed a windows application that uses a SQL Server database with SQL Server authentication (with a username and password) to log in.

The database is located on a local server which uses the same network as my company computers.

Now I have published the application and installed it on my computer (where I developed it and in which I also have the SQL server installed).

I also installed the application on the computers of some colleagues who do not have any program installed  (they do not have Visual Studio or SQL Server installed).

When I try to log in to the application from my computer everything works fine.
(I can enter in application and database communication works very well).

But when I try to log in to the application from other computers (with the same user which I used on my computer before), it does not work.

I get this error:

> Named pipes provider error 40 could not open a connection to SQL Server

I did these steps on the server where the application is located as:

1. Enable TCP / IP in SQL Server Configuration
2. Open Port in Windows Firewall 1433
3. Allow remote connections to this server

Can you help me with any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating a ODBC connection to your machine from the client as a quick test - using the ODBC control panel.  If that works, then check your connection string in the app.  Maybe it's configured as a local connection?  (The connection string would be my first guess.)

There are so many things that can be wrong that it a guessing game.  This link might help.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I tried to Telnet Server and port 1433 from Clients computers and everything is fine. I also checked connection string and I saw that it was (SQL AUTH with username and password). I don't now why it happening. From my computer work perfectly but from colleague's computers doesn't work.